# Join query question that I can't figure out

Tags: android, sqlite

So I have three tables:

```
Table Place:  _id autoincrement not null primary key, name TEXT,place TEXT
Table Food: _id autoincrement not null primary key, food TEXT
Table Person:  _id autoincrement not null primary key, personName TEXT, PLACE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, FOOD_ID INTEGER
```

I want to pull all the food and Place information however, as noted in the person table, there can be a null value for FOOD_ID.  Assume the database is fully populated correctly. How do I query this? I tried to following query:

```
select * from Person,Food,Place where Place._id = Person.PLACE_ID and if not null Person.Food_id Food._id = Person.FOOD_ID
```

But that doesn't work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Place pl
    ON p.PLACE_ID = pl._id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Food f
    ON p.FOOD_ID = f._id
```

Remember, a LEFT OUTER join returns ALL rows in the left table (Person in this case) even when there are no matching rows in the right table. The values for the right side table will all be NULL.

Comment: and what if we want to select only people's name whose is say Jon?